# Periodic solution of an ordinary differential equation through linearization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems

So I have this differential equation
$$x'(t)=ay(t)-x(t)^3 +\epsilon$$
$$y'(t)=-ax(t)-y(t)^2cos(t)-y(t)^3$$
We can rewrite the problem
$$z'(t)=aJz(t)-F(z(t=,t,\epsilon)$$
$$z'(t)=a\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}z(t)-\begin{bmatrix}
    -x(t)^3 +\epsilon \\
   -y(t)^2cos(t)-y(t)^3
\end{bmatrix}$$

We first show with Lyapunov that all the solutions always exist (global). Then we notice that the flow verifies
$$\phi(\epsilon=0,z_0=0)(t)=0$$
We then try to linearize the flow around $(0,0)$, so we look for the differential of the flow on that point. We use the theorem of " differential dependency" not sure about the name in english to calculate the differential to find that the linearized flow can be written as
$$\phi(\epsilon,z,t)=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(at) & sin(at)\\
-sin(at) & cos(at) 
\end{pmatrix}z+\frac{1}{a}\begin{bmatrix}
    sin(at) \\
   -1+cos(at)
\end{bmatrix}\epsilon+K(z,\epsilon,t)$$
That is for $a$ non zero.
Am now asked to show that for $a$ non integer there exists  a neighborhood of $0$ such that for every $\epsilon$ in that neighborhood we have  a 2$\pi$-periodic solution to the problem.
It is sufficient to have $$\phi(\epsilon,z_0)(2\pi)=z_0$$
for some condition $z_0$, and  so injecting in our linearization we find $$\phi(\epsilon,z,2\pi)=z+K(z,\epsilon,t)$$
so for any $\epsilon$ in that neighborhood we can find an initial condition $z_0$ such that $$K(z_0,\epsilon,2\pi)=0$$
$K$ being $C^1$ and $o(e,\rvert\rvert z \lvert \lvert)$
So I'm stuck here, I dont have a clear idea for how to show this.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!